# The Lebesgue measure of the solution space of a specific type of equation

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider the solution space of parameter $x: D = \{x| F(x) = 0, x \in \mathbb{R}^m\}$, where $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \exp\{b_n^T x\}$ for $a_n\in \mathbb{R},b_n \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, n =  1, ..., N$.

Then in nontrivial case, $\mu_l D = 0$.

I think it may be a special case of some theorem. But I cannot find it.

Comment: In the best possible case, $F$ has $0$ is a [regular value](https://diffgeom.subwiki.org/wiki/Regular_value), and then $D$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^m$ of dimension $m-1$. The Lebesgue measure of a submanifold of positive codimension is always zero, since it looks locally like a coordinate hyperplane, up to diffeomorphism. If $0$ is not a regular value, then the situation is a bit nastier, but I guess not too bad. The first case is generic, since you can perturb either $F$ or $0$ a tiny bit to arrive at it.